# Form Processing php

Tags: php, forms, validation, error-handling

I am new here so please point me in the right direction if I am misunderstanding how to submit a question here.

**1.** I am getting warning errors stating that I have "Undefined array keys". I get this before and after the form has been submitted. I have defined the arrays at the top so I am unsure why they are undefined.

**2.** My error trapping is not working if I enter an incorrect phone number format. I initially get the error stating to put it in the right format, but if I put the information in the correct format and submit I still get the error and the phone number resets to what it was initially. I am getting that it is pulling it from the $_GET, but not sure why when it is submitted again it is not updating the $_GET to populate it correctly.

```
<?php

function validate_field_contents($content, $title, $type, $message, ) {
    if($type == 'text') {
        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]/";
        if(!preg_match($string_exp, $content)) {
            $message .= '<li>Please enter a valid ' . strtolower($title) . '.</li>';
        }
    } 
    elseif($type == 'email') {
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
        if(!preg_match($email_exp, $content)) {
            $message .= '<li>Please enter a valid ' . strtolower($title) . '.</li>';
        }
    }
    elseif($type == 'phone'){
        $num_exp = "/^\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/";
         if(!preg_match($num_exp,$content)) {
             {$message .= '<li>Please enter a valid ' . strtolower($title) . ' in the following format (xxx)xxx-xxxx.</li>';}
        }
    }
    elseif($type == 'zip'){
        $num_exp = "/^[0-9]{5}$/";
         if(!preg_match($num_exp,$content)) {
             {$message .= '<li>Please enter a valid ' . strtolower($title) . ' with 5 numbers only.</li>';}
        }
    }
    elseif(empty($_POST['band'])){
            {$message .= '<li>Please select a ' . strtolower($title) . '.</li>';}
    }
    elseif(empty($type == 'color')){
         $message .= '<li>Please select a ' . strtolower($title) . '.</li>';
        }
    elseif(empty($type == 'size')){
         $message .= '<li>Please select a ' . strtolower($title) . '.</li>';
        }
    elseif(empty($type == 'style')){
         $message .= '<li>Please select a ' . strtolower($title) . '.</li>';
        }
    return $message;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so a few things here:

- You don't need the variable assignations at the top.  This is something very important in C and other languages, but PHP doesn't require this.
- Your `if(isset($_GET['firstName'])) $firstName = $_GET['firstName'];` statements are using `$_GET` while your `<form>` tag uses `$_POST` - that's your main issue
- I would recommend using an array of variables, something like this:

  ```
   $address_vars = array(
    array(
       'element_name' => 'firstName',
       'title' => 'First Name',
       'validation' => 'text',
    ),
    array(
       'element_name' => 'lastName',
       'title' => 'Last Name',
       'validation' => 'text',
    ),
  );
  ```

Then you can output the fields programmatically like this:

```
foreach($address_vars as $cur_address_field) {
    ?>
        <label><?php echo $cur_address_field['title']; ?>: <input type = "text" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST[$cur_address_field['element_name']]) ? $_POST[$cur_address_field['element_name']] : ''); ?>" id = "<?php echo $cur_address_field['element_name']; ?>" placeholder = "<?php echo $cur_address_field['title']; ?>" name ="<?php echo $cur_address_field['element_name']; ?>"></label>
    <?php
}
```

This not only cleans up the code quite a bit, but it also makes it much, much easier (and safer) to change/update or even add to the fields.

Then, to validate the fields you can use the `validation` array key I set up as a switch to go through all your fields.  Something like this:

```
foreach($address_vars as $validate_field) {
    if($validate_field['validation'] == 'text') {
        // this is a text-based field, so we check it against the text-only regex
        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
        if(!preg_match($string_exp, $_POST[$validate_field['element_name']])) {
            $message .= '<li>Please enter a ' . strtolower($validate_field['title']) . ' containing letters and spaces only.</li>';
        }
    } elseif($validate_field['validation'] == 'email') {
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
        if(!preg_match($email_exp, $_POST[$validate_field['element_name']])) {
            $message .= '<li>Please enter a valid ' . strtolower($validate_field['title']) . '.</li>';
        }
    }
}
```

- You didn't wire up your product fields correctly.  There's no way for the user-submitted value to 'stick' here, so the field's value is simply lost.  To begin with, we can put these all in an array, similar to what we did with the address fields:

  $product_vars = array(
  array(
  'element_name' => 'band',
  'title' => 'Band',
  'options' => $bands,
  'placeholder' => 'Choose One',
  ),
  array(
  'element_name' => 'color',
  'title' => 'Color',
  'options' => $colors,
  'placeholder' => 'Choose One',
  ),
  );

Then we can use the following for the form:

```
foreach($product_vars as $cur_product) {
    ?>
            <label><?php echo $cur_product['title']; ?>: </label>
                <select name="<?php echo $cur_product['element_name']; ?>" size="1">
                    <option><?php echo $cur_product['placeholder']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                        foreach($cur_product['options'] as $cur_option)
                        {
                            echo "<option value = '".$cur_option."' ".(isset($_POST[$cur_product['element_name']]) && $_POST[$cur_product['element_name']] == $cur_option ? "selected='selected'" : "")."> $cur_option </option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
    <?php
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

**EDIT DUE TO NEW CODE SHARED **

There were again a few things here.  Main items were: the `$product_vars` foreach being outside the `<form>` tag, the `<form>` tag not being set to use `$_POST` despite the rest of the code being set that way, and not adding any validation types.  I've pasted the full code I have, which is working for me.

```php
<?php
        //arrays
        $bands = array ("ACDC", "Journey", "Modest Mouse", "Band of Horses", "Vampire Weekend", "Of Monsters and Men", "Broken Bells", "Phoenix", "Fleetwood Mac", "AJR",);
        $colors = array ("Black", "Navy", "Red", "Orange", "Pink", "Yellow", "Green", "Gray", "White", "Purple",);
        $sizes = array ("X-Small", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "X-Large", "XX-Large", "XXX-Large",);
        $styles = array ("Tank Top", "T-Shirt", "Long Sleeve", "Hoodie", "Sweatshirt", "Jacket",);
        
        $product_vars = array(
        array( 'element_name' => 'band', 'title' => 'Band', 'options' => $bands, 'placeholder' => 'Choose One', ), 
        array( 'element_name' => 'color', 'title' => 'Color', 'options' => $colors, 'placeholder' => 'Choose One', ), 
        array( 'element_name' => 'size', 'title' => 'Size', 'options' => $sizes, 'placeholder' => 'Choose One', ), 
        array( 'element_name' => 'style', 'title' => 'Style', 'options' => $styles, 'placeholder' => 'Choose One', ), 
        );
    
        $address_vars = array(
        array(  'element_name' => 'firstName', 'title' => 'First Name', 'validation' => 'text',),
        array(  'element_name' => 'lastName',   'title' => 'Last Name', 'validation' => 'text',),
        array(  'element_name' => 'email', 'title' => 'Email Address', 'validation' => 'email',),
        array(  'element_name' => 'phone', 'title' => 'Phone Number', 'validation' => 'phone',),
        array(  'element_name' => 'address', 'title' => 'Address', 'validation' => 'address',),
        array(  'element_name' => 'city', 'title' => 'City', 'validation' => 'text',),
        array(  'element_name' => 'state', 'title' => 'State', 'validation' => 'text',),
        array(  'element_name' => 'zip', 'title' => 'Zip Code', 'validation' => 'zip',),
        );
    
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <?php
        foreach($product_vars as $cur_product) {
        ?>
                <label><?php echo $cur_product['title']; ?>: </label>
                    <select name="<?php echo $cur_product['element_name']; ?>" size="1">
                        <option><?php echo $cur_product['placeholder']; ?></option>
                        <?php
                            foreach($cur_product['options'] as $cur_option)
                            {
                                echo "<option value = '".$cur_option."' ".(isset($_POST[$cur_product['element_name']]) && $_POST[$cur_product['element_name']] == $cur_option ? "selected='selected'" : "")."> $cur_option </option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
        <?php
        }
        foreach($address_vars as $cur_address_field) {
        ?>
    
            <label><?php echo $cur_address_field['title']; ?>: 
                <input 
                type = "text" 
                value="<?php echo (isset($_POST[$cur_address_field['element_name']]) ? $_POST[$cur_address_field['element_name']] : ''); ?>" 
                id = "<?php echo $cur_address_field['element_name']; ?>" 
                placeholder = "<?php echo $cur_address_field['title']; ?>" 
                name ="<?php echo $cur_address_field['element_name']; ?>">  
            </label>
            <?php } ?>
                <input type="reset" class="buttons">
                <input type="submit" class="buttons">
            </form>
        <?php


        foreach($address_vars as $validate_field) {
            $message = validate_field_contents($_POST[$validate_field['element_name']], $validate_field['title'], $validate_field['validation'], $message);
        }
        ?>
    
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>T-Shirt Form</title>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-prod.css">
            <script src="..js/script.js" defer></script>
        </head>
        <body>          
    
            <?php
            if($message) {
                echo '<p>'.$message.'</p>';
            } else {
            ?>

            <!--display processed information here-->
            <h3 class="subheaderone">Thank you for your order!</h3><br>
            <h3 class = "subheadertwo">Product:</h3>
            <div class = "output">
            
                <h3 class = "subheadertwo">Shipping & Contact Information:</h3>
                <?php foreach($address_vars as $cur_address) {
                    echo '<p>' . $cur_address['title'] . ': ' . (isset($_POST[$cur_address['element_name']]) ? $_POST[$cur_address['element_name']] : '') . '</p>';
                } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="another"> 
                <nav><a href="./products.php"> Submit Another Form</a></nav> 
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </body>
    </html>


<?php

function validate_field_contents($content, $title, $type, $message) {
    if($type == 'text') {
        // this is a text-based field, so we check it against the text-only regex
        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
        if(!preg_match($string_exp, $content)) {
            $message .= '<li>Please enter a valid ' . strtolower($title) . ' containing letters and spaces only.</li>';
        }
    } elseif($type == 'email') {
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
        if(!preg_match($email_exp, $content)) {
            $message .= '<li>Please enter a valid ' . strtolower($title) . '.</li>';
        }
    }
    return $message;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help cleaning up my code. That was very helpful.

Comment: I made the edits that you suggested and included a submit button and clear button as well as the other fields/variables needed for the address and drop-down. I changed my ifset to $_POST as well. However, it still isn't saving the submitted info (I see the address info in the $_GET var_dump array but not the drop down info), populating an error if there is one, or displaying the form to submit or the thank you message without the form showing. I am also still getting the Warning: Undefined array key "______" message for all of the address variables.

Comment: Could you maybe edit your question with the updated code?  Also, take a look at which line numbers are referenced when it says 'Undefined array key'

Comment: I updated the code to what I have. I tried adding in the variables that I had at the top and that solved some and made others. It's also all populating at the same time instead so I added a comment at the top of my submission on the desired output that I am trying to achieve if that helps. The other errors are from my HTML output when submitted. I am thinking maybe I need an "if(empty($_POST['submit-button]))" statement for if empty and if !empty to populate the form or populate the thank you. I tried to input that into the coding but I couldn't get that to work right either.

Comment: @monkey84 I've edited my answer with the code I wound up with, which is working for me.  You'll want to add further validation rules and such in the `validate_field_contents` function.

Comment: Thank you, that did help. I am still getting the warning undefined array for this part of the code. I checked the arrays that it would pull from and I don't understand why the warning would be flagging.

`foreach($address_vars as $validate_field) 
{$message = validate_field_contents($_POST[$validate_field['element_name']], $validate_field['title'], $validate_field['validation'], $message);"}`

Comment: The errors also show before the form has been filled out instead of showing after it has been submitted if there is a problem. I tried to wrap it with `if(empty($_POST['submit-button']))`? but that doesn't seem to work for that issue but did solve my issue of only showing the form or thank you message. Any ideas?

In addition, how do I get the drop-downs to stick if the user didn't fill out the info. The address is sticking that was filled out but not those.

I also added additional validation contents but am unsure how to validate the drop-downs.

Comment: I updated my code after playing around with it today trying to get it to work correctly. I am still getting the warning on that address line and am getting the error codes prior to hitting the submit button. After submitting I am not getting the vaidation to go through for the drop-downs (not sure how to validate these) and get them to echo when everything has been filled out.